# HTTPS Version of $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] PHP

Tags: php, proxy, proxies

Does anyone know if there is a HTTPS 'version' of $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] therefore I can resolve https proxies? If not, does anyone know a way to resolve the actual IP of HTTPS proxy user in PHP?

Comment: Take a look at the way CodeIgniter does it: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Input.php (currently starts on line 365)

Comment: that variable will be there if the reverse proxy inserted the X-Forwarded-For header.  Depending on the proxy configuration this can be done for either plaintext (http) or https.